# Remove connected objects from binary image

Tags: image-processing, binary-image

I have a binary skeletonized image with many blobs in the form of vertical lines, most of them are straight and some of them are intersecting each other. I want to remove all those blobs which are intersecting each other. Is there any way?

I have tried bwconncomp and then PixelIdxList to remove the intersecting blobs (as they would have the largest num of pixels) but it removes only the biggest one not the other ones. I am looking for an efficient way to remove all those blobs which are a combination of two or more than two blobs or in other words if they are intersecting each other.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Seeing your image would help - maybe you have some more points now...